# Simple Slideshow on Hover, Slideshow stops on mouseleave

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, slideshow, mouseenter

This is my first post. My code works in chrome and safari, but the slideshow won't stop in firefox. I want to show a live version of this code to make it easier, but I'm working locally. I'm wondering if its because I wrote it with hover instead of mouseover and mouseleave, but I dont know how to write it out correctly that way. There may even be an error in this code, but the browser is not detecting it.

HTML:

```
<div class="fadelinks">

   <a href="#"> <img src=""/> </a>
   <a href="#"> <img src=""/> </a>
   <a href="#"> <img src=""/> </a>
   <a href="#"> <img src=""/> </a>

</div>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$(".fadelinks").each(function(){
    var $this = this;
    $($this).hover(function(){

      $('> :gt(0)', $this).hide();
      timer = setInterval(function(){$('> :first- child',$this).fadeOut()
      .next().fadeIn().end().appendTo($this);}, 1500);
      }, function() {
      clearInterval(timer);

    });

  });


});
```

Answer (score 0):

a simpler way to achieve is to add onmouseover = "mouseoverFunction();" onmouseout = "mouseoutFunction()" to each img tag
then in javascript 
mouseoverFunction()

loop through image array
show next
wait

mouseoutFunction()
stop looping

you do not need the a tags

Answer (score 0):

well you want that on mouse hover your images start sliding here is another code i am not so good in jquery but here is the code:

css

```
   #fadelinks{
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

set your image height and width equal to the width and height of `fadelinks`

HTML

```
    <div class="fadelinks">

       <a id="same1" href="#"> <img src=""/> </a>
       <a id="same2" href="#"> <img src=""/> </a>
       <a id="same3" href="#"> <img src=""/> </a>
       <a id="same4" href="#"> <img src=""/> </a>

    </div>
<button onclick="slid1">image1<button>
<button onclick="slid2">image2<button>
<button onclick="slid3">image3<button>
<button onclick="slid4">image4<button>
```

jquery

```
 var slide1 = function(){

    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#same1, #same2, #same3, #sam4").fadeout(100);$("#same1").fadeIn();
    });
}
  var slide2 = function(){

    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#same1, #same2, #same3, #sam4").fadeout(100);$("#same2").fadeIn();
    });
} var slide3 = function(){

    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#same1, #same2, #same3, #sam4").fadeout(100);$("#same3").fadeIn();
    });
} var slide4 = function(){

    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#same1, #same2, #same3, #sam4").fadeout(100);$("#same4").fadeIn();
    });
```

you will understand what will this do but as i told you i am not so good in jquery so i have done this in you know in noob style. but from this you might get the idea and you can intregate this with event handler  `mousehover` and `mouseout` and also use `setinterval` to slide automatically.

thanks.